# How to use openssl on mono?

Tags: f#, openssl, mono

I can use ssl in windows:

first make a cert:

```
makecert -r -pe -n “CN=TestServer” -ss Root -sky exchange
```

then

```
let store = new X509Store(StoreName.Root)
store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite)
let certs = store.Certificates.Find(X509FindType.FindBySubjectName,"TestServer", false)
let x509 = certs.[0]

let sslStream = new SslStream(client.GetStream(), false)

sslStream.AuthenticateAsServer(x509, false, SslProtocols.Tls, true);
```

Now I can use tls connection

I want to know how to write the equal code on mono on linux?

Comment: What errors are you getting on linux/mono when running it?

Comment: You should ask a specific question for a particular problem. Since Stack Overflow hides the Close reason from you: *"Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it."*

Comment: Why is this question tagged as C# when your code is clearly F#?